# scipy.signal.deconvolve returns an array of NaNs

Tags: python, deconvolution

I am trying to implement a deconvolution-based event detection algorithm in python, but scipy.signal.deconvolve doesn't seem to work in my case. Here is a basic example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve, deconvolve, unit_impulse

def event(x, start, a, t1, t2):
    """Event model based on two-exponent differential.

    Positional arguments:
    x - time array
    start - event start time
    a - event amplitude
    t1 - rise tau
    t2 - decay tau
    """
    y = -np.exp(-(x - start) / t1) + np.exp(-(x - start) / t2)
    n = a / y.max()
    res = n * np.array([0 if t < start else i for t, i in zip(x, y)])
    return(res)



signal = unit_impulse(1000, idx=100)
ev = event(np.arange(300), 0, -10, 1, 5)
conv = convolve(signal, ev)
signal_recovered = deconvolve(conv, ev)[0]
```

Here, signal_recovered always ends up containing all NaNs, except for the first value, which is Inf. Why does it happen?

Comment: Have you tried looking at your variables after every step to identify where the NaNs are introduced?

Comment: As you can see from the minimal example, NaNs don't appear before the deconvolution step.

Comment: Well, it's not obvious just from looking at your code. Anyway, now you may consider reading the docs for `deconvolve` to figure out if its arguments are valid, asking the author, or reading its source code.

Comment: If for other reasons you have to deconvolve you have to, but deconvolution is always tricky, usually because of some division by zero. For a function such as you have and also data obtained in an experiment, iterative re-convolution (with a known function) with non-linear least squares works well.